# Is there another interjection that can be used in this example?

Tags: interjections

'O people!'

Can anyone give me an alternative interjection for 'O' in this example?

Comment: What sort of interjection do you want? That little sentence could mean a lot of things as I see it, most of which depend on context...as psmears points out in his answer, I just noticed. Still, a comment can't go amiss...

Comment: "O" is not really an interjection there; rather, it is a vocative marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context... what sort of situation is it for?

If it's to get the attention of a crowd, then maybe:

> Hey, people!

or, more politely

> Excuse me, people!

would do the trick. If, on the other hand, it's the start of some sort of formal address, then maybe

> Dear people,

would be the way to start (although perhaps "Ladies and Gentlemen" would be more conventional).

Comment: As an opening attention-getting pragmatic marker: _NOW_, Ladies and Gentlemen ... . As a refocusing marker, _RIGHT_ is often used, but is even more informal. A spoon on a champagne flute is a non-verbal pragmatic marker often used at various functions.